# Can't import Brain.JS into my NodeJS script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a neural network using brain.js. However, NodeJS doesn't allow me to do that neither with `require('brain.js')` nor with `import 'brain.js'`.
Here is my code:

```
const brain = require('brain.js')

const config = {
    iterations: 15000,
    log: true,
    logPeriod: 500,
    layers: [10]
}

const net = new brain.recurrent.LSTM()

const conjunctions = {
    0: 'Именительный',
    1: 'Родительный',
    2: 'Дательный',
    3: 'Винительный',
    4: 'Творительный',
    5: 'Предложный'
}

const inputData = [
    // some data for training
]

const test = 'Дельфина'

net.train(inputData)
const output = net.run(test)
console.log(`${conjunctions[output]} падеж`)
```

However, it shows me next error when running with `require('brain.js')`:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:         c:\Coding\Labs\Node.JS\MochaTest\node_modules\brain.js\src\index.js
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Coding\Labs\Node.JS\MochaTest\index.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14) {
      code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
```

}

And next error when running with `import * as brain from 'brain.js'`:

```
(node:2648) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///c:/Coding/Labs/Node.JS/MochaTest/node_modules/brain.js/src/index.js:1
const activation = require('./activation');
                   ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///c:/Coding/Labs/Node.JS/MochaTest/node_modules/brain.js/src/index.js:1:20
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:109:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:133:24)
```

What should I do and how to import it right when using NodeJS 13.2.0? I have only brain.js and Mocha installed in this module.

Answer (score 1):

You can import brainjs like that :

```
import brainjs from 'brain.js/src'
```

As mentioned here : https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/issues/80

Answer (score 0):

After looking up some [tutorials](https://stackabuse.com/neural-networks-in-javascript-with-brain-js/), I think you import it by using `const brain = require('brain')`.

Comment: I tried that, but it said `Can't find module 'brain'`

Answer (score 0):

brain js should be installed, you can do it with npm but remember that brain do have system dependencies,
Usually people forget to install python (I don't know your system but a lot of server are "empty" when you start using them)

Mac OS X
Python 2.7
XCode

Ubuntu/Debian
Python 2.7
A GNU C++ environment (available via the build-essential package on apt)
libxi-dev
Working and up to date OpenGL drivers
GLEW
pkg-config

windows
Python 2.7
Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools 2015
run in cmd: npm config set msvs_version 2015
run in cmd: npm config set python python2.7

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTD5f.png)

just remove "type":"module" in the package.json

Comment: Why would OP change global settings just to fix this bug? It's likely to break other things.